# Query Parameter description in ring-swagger

Tags: clojure, swagger, compojure-api

I'm using ring-swagger via compojure-api. I have a few query parameters and I'm struggling to find a way to add a description to a single query parameter. I can add the summary of the entire endpoint but that's not enough.

Is it possible to add a swagger description to a single query parameter using ring-swagger/compojure-api?

Comment: Please add to your question what you tried already and why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compojure.api.sweet/describe`.

For example:

```
(GET "/hello" []
  :query-params [name :- (describe String "This is the swagger description for the parameter")]
  (ok {:message (str "Hello, " name)}))
```